# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS.obj'

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-c++-2015

I add `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS` in preprocessor definition in my C++ project, but I see this error:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS.obj'

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: For some reason you have a compile setting passed to the linker.

Comment: It would think that the deprecated functions that you want to use anyway are in a distinct OBJ file that cannot be found so the program cannot be linked properly. By the way, the best solution is probably to update the code that would generate the warnings so that it does not depends on obsolete stuff anymore.